# Обновить переменную в памяти

Tags: python, python-3.x

Приведу пример кода

```
cat = 1
answer = cat
cat = 2
print(answer)
```

Как сделать так,чтобы вывелось 2,само собой без повторного `answer = cat`

Answer (score 4):

самый простой способ - через списки:

```
a = [1]
b = a
print(b[0])
# 1
a[0] = 2
print(b[0])
# 2
```